# Signal out of range message at boot time

Tags: boot, grub2, monitor

I have gone through all the posts and I am pretty sure I know how to fix it, but I can't seem to be able to get to a prompt.

I see GRUB loading and then nothing from that point forward. Immediately after post I see a flashing cursor in the upper left corner. A few seconds later the monitor displays a message saying signal out of range.  No keystrokes at any point give me access to a login prompt. I'm not sure what to do at this point.

I installed 16.04 and 17.10 with the same result.

Comment: When does the "Out of range" message come up? What does this have to do with the monitor?

Comment: Immediatly after post i see a flashing cursornin the upper left corner. I few seconds later the monitor displays a message saying signal out of range.

Comment: And yes i was loading 16.04 with the same prob so i tries the other version

Comment: OK. Please [edit] your question to add details.

Comment: Reloading it again now installing just basic server.

Answer (score 3):

At first you should determine specification of your monitor - especially its native resolution.
Then you can adjust it manually in configuration file.

Try the following:

1. press <kbd>Shift</kbd> during boot to access GRUB menu
2. in GRUB press <kbd>e</kbd>, then

   - add `nomodeset` to the end of `linux` line OR
   - add `vga=795` (1280x1024, see other options [here](http://pierre.baudu.in/other/grub.vga.modes.html)) to the end of `linux` line
3. then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

Remember good value of `vga=` and then place it in `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash vga=795"
```

Then execute `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

Comment: I would love to if i could access grub ! Thats the issue i cant bring it up

Comment: It is very strange. I went to similar issue with HP ProLiant, but GRUB opened normally. "Out of range" message was shown by monitor after GRUB.

Comment: Got it ! Not sure why but i let go of shift just after the loading grub screen and it booted to a login prompt. I am good to go thanks all

Comment: I'm getting signal out of range message after logging in to my account with Xorg

Answer (score 1):

On *live* media (eg. Ubuntu install media), I've had this issue occur because of a bad write to media.

If you're using *live* media, did you

(a) Validate your ISO ?

https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0

(b) Validate your write to install media

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck

Ubuntu 20.04 & later media self-verify, but if this issue occurs on the first boot, you won't be able complete the validation (or at least see results), so I usually shutdown using SysRq keystrokes, then attempt to boot the thumb-drive on another box.  Not all boxes will experience this issue, but if I have problems on the second box, I assume it was a bad-write and usually return to check the ISO & re-write the ISO to my media (usually thumb-drive).  *I have booted before on a third box for confirmation of failed boot, but usually don't consider this necessary*.